# Android app buttons outside of Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview i am implementing by calling a new activity.  The layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listWrap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/testbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textSize="13dp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/testbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/hello" /></RelativeLayout>
```

When the activity loads the button is at the bottom but once the list is loaded instead of the list fields the button is appearing in every list item.  How can I make this button stay at the bottom and have a list above?

Comment: In Your Code in ListView the ID is  android:id="@id/android:list" , it should be android:id="@+id/android:list"  '+' is Missing, Instead of Using LinearLayout, use Relative Layout Only.

Answer (score 0):

Keep Button in separate layout and check it once

Answer (score 0):

you can change the height of listview set according to view in graphical layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:id="@+id/lv1"
android:background="#000"
android:scrollingCache="false"/>
<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="OK"
 android:id="@+id/btnok"
 />
```

Answer (score -2):

Never tried that (I don't find it looks nice) but I would try to add weights or to give a minHeight to the button if I was you.